# How to store an iOS game save file in multiple devices? (Without remote servers)

Tags: ios

I've been developing an iOS game for iPhone. My game saves the progress as a couple of .plist documents in the device.

I have come to realize that when I install a game in my iPhone, this same game is installed in my iPad. And then it struck me: how would I manage save files? I mean, I'd like the player to be able to continue playing from where they left no matter what device are they using... without using remote servers.

What have you done to address this issue?

Comment: "without my own servers" or "without remote servers"?  The subject line disagrees with the body text.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this would be possible over the internet. Having mobile devices connect to each other, without an intermediate server is near impossible. Since one or the other would have to broadcast its location in someway that the other could respond to. I'm not familiar with a way to do that if the devices don't already know about each other.

However, on a much smaller network, like a home wifi network. This is reasonable. Both devices would need to be connected to the same wifi network. From there they can communicate and sync save files.

Answer (score 2):

I would say try using iCloud. But technically, it is a remote server. At least you do not need to handle anything on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Game center, there are two systems that I know which can help you:

1. GameKit provides interfaces to transfer data over the Bluetooth, I'm not sure about the specifications but it's possible! here is an example: [iPhone Bluetooth Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502)
2. GameKit also offers support for Turned based games over the internet, If I'm not wrong you can use this feature to sync player profile on both devices. [GKTurnBasedMatch Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

There might be other options available too also you might want to take a look at both OpenFeint and GameKit for similar or better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do it via email? Have your game communicate with SMTP/IMAP, let your user log in with an email address, then send your save game data. The other device would then check for the particular mail with the save game then store it.

You'd need to be connected to the Internet though.

Since your game is mobile, Gajoo's suggestion about Bluetooth sounds best.

Comment: Using E-Mail *is* using a remote Server though :)

Comment: But it wouldn't be such a problem, email servers are so ubiquitous and accessible to anyone